# Preserve file creation time with Java

Tags: java

I wrote a little copy tool in java to copy .mp3 files on my USB stick. When new files are copied, some file attributes are preserved, but not the creation time.

To copy files I use:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
static void copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile, boolean preserveFileDate)
```

FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, newTargetFile, preserveFileDate);

So my question, is there a way to preserve the file creation time? If not, I think I set up a class to copy with windows robocopy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Java 7+, you can use:

```
Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```

If that does not copy the creation time (it does on my machine), you can also manually set it:

```
Path source = ...;
Path target = ...;
Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);

FileTime creationTime  = (FileTime) Files.readAttributes(source, "creationTime").get("creationTime");
Files.setAttribute(target, "creationTime", creationTime);
```

Comment: This is a recommended approach, if you are using JDK 7 or higher, that is.

Comment: Thanks, but file creation time is not preserves with this method.

Comment: @user3143553 It works for me - I have added something which may work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#basic

It's possible to get and set files attributes like creation time.